# Template type deduction with variadic template for function calls

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, variadic-templates, template-argument-deduction

I'm using VC++ `/std:c++latest` and I want to determine the RET-Type, Class-Type and argument types of a member function passed as template paramter to a struct.
I found a way to do this:

```
template <auto MEMBER>
class C;
template <class RET, class T, class... ARGS, RET(T::*MEMBER)(ARGS...)>
class C<MEMBER>
{
public:
    template <class... ARGS2>
    RET operator()(ARGS2&&... args)
    {
        // place holder
        (reinterpret_cast<T*>(0)->*MEMBER)(std::forward<ARGS2>(args)...);
    }
};
struct A
{
    void f(int, int) {}
};
int main()
{
    C<&A::f> c; // error C2079: 'instance' uses undefined class 'C'
    c(5, 5);
}
```

But this solution is only working with g++.

So

1. is this a bug in VC++?
2. is there an other way to achieve the same thing?

Comment: What isn't "working" elsewhere? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `reinterpret_cast<T*>(nullptr)->*MEMBER` I really hope that that is placeholder syntax...

Comment: @Rakete1111 yes it is and it's absolutly not concering my question

Comment: The spec says "When the value of the argument corresponding to a non-type template parameter P that is declared with a dependent type is deduced from an expression, the template parameters in the type of P are deduced from the type of the value.", so your code seems valid. However, this rule was added only in C++17 I believe, when auto-template-parameters were added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint of @max66 let me figure out, that I do not need to deduce the arguments of the function, whereat the return type and class type can easily be deduced.

```
template <auto MEMBER>
struct C
{
    template <class RET, class T, class... ARGS>
    static constexpr auto deduce_RET(RET (T::*member)(ARGS...)) -> RET;
    template <class RET, class T, class... ARGS>
    static constexpr auto deduce_T(RET (T::*member)(ARGS...)) -> T;
    using RET = decltype(deduce_RET(MEMBER));
    using T = decltype(deduce_T(MEMBER));
    template <class... ARGS>
    RET operator()(ARGS&&... args)
    {
        return (reinterpret_cast<T*>(0)->*MEMBER)(std::forward<ARGS>(args)...);
    }
};
```

Edit: The bug got fixed for Visual Studio 2019: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/464355/error-c2079-instance-uses-undefined-class-c.html

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer (sorry) but a long comment: if you want perfect forwarding, you need universal references in a template function/method

I mean... I suggest to rewrite `operator()` as follows or something similar (I've also added the perfect forwarding for a `T` object)

```
template <typename U, typename ... As>
RET operator()(U && u, As && ... args)
{
    (std::forward<U>(u).*MEMBER)(std::forward<As>(args)...);
}
```

So you can write (in g++ and clang++, at least)

```
A  a;
C<&A::f> c;
c(a, 5, 5);
```

Comment: I knew I'm doing something wrong with the perfect forwarding part, thank you.

Comment: @JulianH - You're welcome. You also need the `&&` (`ARGS2 && ... args`)